# не работает декодер

Tags: python, строки

Нужно создать программу для шифрования введенной строки со смещением через команды(chr,ord) по таблице asii, и расшифровать эту строку не зная на сколько символов было смещение, в 9 строке ловлю ошибку unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' подскажите как исправить

```
string = input('Введите строку: ')
for i in string:
    code=ord(i)-5
    print(code,end=' ')

j = 0
k = 1
while j<255:
    decode = chr(code) - k
    k-=1
    print(decode)
    print('Продолжить?')
    answer = input('')
    if answer == 'да':
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: м.б. `decode = chr(code - k)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string = input('Введите строку: ')
code = ''
for i in string:
    code += str(ord(i)-5) + ' '
# print(code)

k = 1
while True:
    decode = ''
    for i in code.split():
        a = chr(int(i) - k)
        decode += a
    k-=1
    print(decode)
    answer = input('Продолжить да(1), нет(0)\n')
    if answer == '1':
        continue
    elif answer == '0':
        break
```

Вот что показывает на тестах (если я правильно понял, что требуется):

```
Введите строку: Привет
ЙквЬЯм
Продолжить да(1), нет(0)
1
КлгЭан
Продолжить да(1), нет(0)
1
ЛмдЮбо
Продолжить да(1), нет(0)
1
МнеЯвп
Продолжить да(1), нет(0)
1
Ножагр
Продолжить да(1), нет(0)
1
Опзбдс
Продолжить да(1), нет(0)
1
Привет
Продолжить да(1), нет(0)
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```